# Uploading access database on shared hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, io, shared-hosting

I've got an application where I upload an access database to the server, then read that database and import it into my SQL database.  However, this is the first time I've tried to do something like this on shared hosting, and I can't change the write permissions on the upload folder so I can't upload the db?

Anyone know of anything else I could try?  I looked into IsolatedStorageFileStream, but not sure that would be any good for reading from the database file once it was in isolated storage

Thanks

UPDATE:
Ok, this was the message I got from the hosting company:

```
    I'm afraid it's not possible to amend the permissions to allow 
this to work in Integrated mode as it would pose a security risk 
in a shared environment. Its unfortunate that your application 
wouldn't function with a custom web directory/application as this 
has been used as a work around previously.

    I can understand the frustration with this as its basically a 
failure between two Microsoft technologies which are meant to work 
together. Your web application runs under Identity impersonate and 
the user it runs as has read,write,modify permisions to all your 
web directories, when run in Integrated mode this aspect isn't respected.
```

This, combined with the fact that i can't run wildcard script mapping on the server, means it won't work in classic or integrated mode.  Has anyone come across these issues before?

Comment: If you can upload the files that comprise the website, then you can upload the file that contains the database, surely?

Comment: Yes I could upload it direct, but I want to have an File Upload control on the page and allow admin users to upload new databases every week.  It is uploading via the website that is the problem as I get an Access Denied error when it tries to upload to the folder.

Comment: I guess there's a bit more to your overall requirements - presumably this is some "end-user" created Access file that has to be uploaded via a web interface? I.e. they can't be trusted to either FTP the file up, or there's some processing happening that means you/they can't import it directly to the remote DB? Most professional shared hosting options will allow you to mark one or more folders as writeable for uploads (or will do it for you via a support request)

Comment: The hosting company said earlier that they can't.  I've just raised another support ticket to ask again if there is anything they can do to change the permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Moved hosting company update to original question as per Alex's advice.

Final answer:  Well, I never got the solution I was hoping for - the only thing I could do was upgrade to cloud hosting as the site wouldn't work in classic mode as they wouldn't let me use wildcard mapping.

I wasn't aware how spoiled I'd been by using servers hosted by my company for doing all commercial projects.  Didn't realise how much of a hassle it was to use .net/MVC on shared hosting. If the last week is anything to go by, it looks like a minefield.

Comment: Hi @e-on you should edit your question with extra detail, rather than adding it as an answer. Helps keep things tidy.